# FileZilla FTP Error - 426 Connection Closed; aborted transfer of "filename"

Tags: ftp, wireshark

I'm trying to transfer a file to an FTP server but I get the error on the title: "426 Connection Closed; aborted transfer of "XYZ".

Here are some info:

- I can establish the connection, change directory, transfer a file from FTP server to the client.
- Both port 21 and 20 is allowed through the firewalls and eventually reach the FTP server.
- Server is filezilla, client is either windows ftp client of WinSCP. (same error)

[image: packet capture]

As you can see on the picture, the server is sending a RST packet but I have no idea why. Also, this appears to work intermittently (once in last 7 days)

Can anyone see what is wrong with this picture? What would make an FTP server reset the connection?